# How add execution permissions to file generated by CMake?

Tags: cmake

I have a file, *wrapper.sh.in*, that has something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
DEPENDENCY_VERSION=@dependency_VERSION@
/location/of/installed/dependency/${DEPENDENCY_VERSION}/some_script.sh "$@"
```

This *wrapper.sh.in* script has the usual file permissions for a regular non-executable files (0644), but I need the file generated by CMake to have execution permissions, since it is a script, and therefore meant to be run.

Here's what I am currently doing in my CMakeLists.txt in order to generate my wrapper script:

```
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.sh.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.sh
    @ONLY
    )
```

Here's what I've tried for changing the permissions for the generated *wrapper.sh* script.

Attempt #1 (FAIL):

```
file(
    COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.sh
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
    )
```

Attempt #2 (FAIL):

```
install(
    FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.sh
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
    COMPONENT runtime
    )
```

What would be the correct way to change the file permissions of the generated *wrapper.sh* script to those of a normal script (0755)?

Comment: Is it meant to be run during build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Copying* file "at place" is bad idea in most cases.

Instead, configure file into one (intermediate) place, and copy it (with changed permissions) into the final location:

```
configure_file(
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/wrapper.sh.in
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp/wrapper.sh
    @ONLY
    )

file(
    COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tmp/wrapper.sh
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
    FILE_PERMISSIONS OWNER_READ OWNER_WRITE OWNER_EXECUTE GROUP_READ GROUP_EXECUTE WORLD_READ WORLD_EXECUTE
    )
```

Comment: Does it support the three digit octal notation (e.g. `755`)?

Comment: Documentation for command flow [file(CHMOD)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#chmod) tells that only string literals are supported for the permissions. Command flow `file(COPY)` doesn't describe possible values for FILE_PERMISSIONS, but I guess possible values are the same. That is, a notation like `755` is not supported.